# error downloading laravel/nexmo via composer

Tags: php, laravel, vonage

When iam trying to download the nexmo package via composer i get stopped.

```
composer require nexmo/laravel
```

I have also tried to restrict with lower version like this

```
composer require nexmo/laravel version ^1.0.0
```

What can i do? Iam quite new to Laravel and the exception text does not tell me much so would really appriciate some help. Thanks in advance

php-version: 7.1.25

Laravel Framework 5.8.38

i get this error:

````
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.38, required as 5.6.*) is satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.38] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability. 
  Problem 2
    - illuminate/support v6.8.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.7.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.6.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.6.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.6.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.5.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.5.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.5.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.4.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.3.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.9 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.8 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.7 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.6 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.5 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.4 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.3 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.24 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.23 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.22 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.21 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.20 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.2 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.19 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.18 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.17 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.16 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.15 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.14 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.13 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.12 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.11 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.10 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.1 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.20.0 requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.19.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.19.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.9 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.8 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.7 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.6 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.5 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.43 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.42 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.41 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.40 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.4 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.39 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.38 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.37 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.36 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.35 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.34 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.33 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.32 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.31 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.30 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.3 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.29 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.28 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.27 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.26 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.25 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.24 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.23 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.22 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.21 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.20 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.19 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.18 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.17 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.16 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.15 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.14 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.13 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.12 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.11 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.10 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.18.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.17.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.17.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.16.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.15.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.15.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.14.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.13.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.13.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.12.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.11.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.10.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.1.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.0.4 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.0.3 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.0.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.0.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support v6.0.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support 6.x-dev requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework 6.x-dev requires php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) overridden 
by "config.platform.php" version (7.1.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Conclusion: remove jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.7
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.40
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
    - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb (locked at v3.6.7, required as ^3.4) -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.6.7].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.7 requires illuminate/support ^5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.38, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.36, v6.18.37, v6.18.38, v6.18.39, v6.18.4, v6.18.40, v6.18.41, v6.18.42, v6.18.43, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.19.0, v6.19.1, v6.2.0, v6.20.0, v6.20.1, v6.20.10, v6.20.11, v6.20.12, v6.20.13, v6.20.14, v6.20.15, v6.20.16, v6.20.17, v6.20.18, v6.20.19, v6.20.2, v6.20.20, v6.20.21, v6.20.22, v6.20.23, v6.20.24, v6.20.3, v6.20.4, v6.20.5, v6.20.6, v6.20.7, v6.20.8, v6.20.9, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.8.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev, v5.8.38].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev       
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.40, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].```



Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
````

Comment: upgrade your php version to ^7.2

Comment: Is there anyway i can get it to work with current php version? @dev_mustafa

Comment: I dont think my php version is the problem hence i tested to download earlier/earliest versions of nexmo

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to install it. Try `composer require laravel/nexmo-notification-channel --with-dependencies`

If that doesn't help, remove your `composer.lock` and `vendor` dir, add the dependency to your `composer.json` and run `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have set your PHP version to 7.1, but it looks like `illuminate/support` you are trying to install requires 7.2, even outside our Nexmo package. You'll need to edit your `config.platform.php` file with a more appropriate PHP version.

Comment: But theres got to be a nexmo version for older php and older laravel versions?. I have tried even nexmo 1.0 and get the same response

Comment: The problem isn't specifically with the `nexmo/laravel` package ... some other package is trying to use `illuminate/support` 6.x, which isn't compatible with PHP 7.1. `nexmo/laravel` 2.x supports that package from 5.2 onward, and `nexmo/laravel` 1.x only supports 5.2. Some other package is requiring v6 of `illuminate/support`

Comment: For a test, delete your `vendor/` folder and just run a `composer install` and see if your packages even reconcile properly. If it works, your `vendor/` folder was polluted with upgraded packages composer didn't recognize. If it doesn't work, then delete the `composer.lock` file and try `composer install` again. If it still fails, your `package.json` has conflicting packages and you'll need to reconcile that before you can install any further packages.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
composer require laravel/nexmo-notification-channel nexmo/laravel 2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

for laravel 8 ,
you can use version 2.4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).